# How do you say images inside a link with no chance for misinterpretation?

Tags: passive-voice

I want to say that the images are inside the links and can only be viewed when he or she visits the links.

```
The images are within links
The images are inside links
The images are embedded within links
The images are linked
```

I am concerned that the sentences above might indicate that the images are either just thumbnails or merely inside the anchor tags.

How should I construct the sentence If I want no chance for misinterpretation?

Comment: "Please visit/open the links to see  the images." - "The images are available in the links"

Comment: I actually need to say something like "Saving images _that can only be viewed by visiting each link_ is a hard job." Is there anyway to shorten the italicized portion of the sentence to be more concise?

Comment: Images are linked (to).

Comment: How about "Saving images to be visited by thumbnail links is ... "? Is this construction grammatically acceptable?

Comment: "The images can be viewed by following the links" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the images are linked** seems like  a good option, however is informal to the reader. As a native English speaker, it seems that the best option is the third, as you are saying that the images are connected to the page through those links.

Comment: "embedded images" are (embedded) directly in the page, so "following the link" is not necessary. Images accessible after clicking a link are LINKED, not EMBEDDED.